# How to set up a rule in TeamCity to force clean check out directory

Tags: teamcity

My user case is like this:

- if there is a file (*.clean) checked in under directory or any of subdirectories of \mySource. In other words, the code changes we make, which will trigger a build, contain a file named like *.clean.
- then perform a clean up of check-out directory
- run the build
  Is that something we can do in TeamCity? Can we set up a rule to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I see a real need for this: Either (a) you're going to leave the file checked in to source control, in which case TeamCity has a checkbox  in project settings for always deleting the workspace before building. Or (b) you want to check the file in to make the next build clean, in which case, the `...` icon next to the build button can do that for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to clean the folders manually, since Teamcity has an option to force cleaning after each check-out: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Clean+Checkout